# accessing static field of class from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, static, el

In a web app, my servlet is printing html as below

```
protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType( "text/html" );
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

        pw.println( "<html><head></head><body>" );
        printBody( pw );
        pw.println( "</body></html>" );
    }
```

where `printBody` is

```
private void printBody( PrintWriter pw ) {
        pw.println( "<form id='pool' method='POST'>" );
        pw.println( "<table>" );
        pw.println( "<tr><th>Home Team</th><th>Away Team</th><th>Tiebreaker?</th></tr>" );

        BettingPoolGame[] games = BettingPool.getGames();
        for (int i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
             pw.println( "<tr><td><input name='home" + i + "' value='" + games[i].getHomeTeam() + "'></td>" );
             pw.println( "<td><input name='away" + i + "' value='" + games[i].getAwayTeam() + "'></td>" );
             pw.print( "<td><input type='radio' name='tiebreaker' value='" + i + "'" );
             if (i == BettingPool.getTieBreakerIndex()) pw.print( " checked" );
             pw.println( " /></td></tr>" );

        }
        pw.println( "</table>" );
        if (BettingPool.isEditable()) {
            pw.println( "<input type='submit' name='save' value='Save' />" );
            pw.println( "<input type='submit' name='save' value='Open Pool' />" );
        }
        pw.println( "</form>" );
    }
```

The `BettingPool` class has some static fields and their accessors

```
public class BettingPool {
     private static int tieBreakerIndex;
     ...
     public static int getTieBreakerIndex() {
        return tieBreakerIndex;
    }
    ...
  }
```

I would like to use a jsp page instead of the printBody() method and tried this

```
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="bettingpool" class="dyna.pool.BettingPool"></jsp:useBean>
<h3>pooleditorform</h3>
<form id='pool' method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr><th>Home Team</th><th>Away Team</th><th>Tiebreaker?</th></tr>
        <c:forEach items="${games}" var="x" varStatus="status">
            <tr><td><input name='home${status.index}' value='${x._homeTeam}' ></td>
            <td><input name='away${status.index }' value='${x._awayTeam}'></td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='tiebreaker' value='${status.index}'/></td></tr>
            <c:if test="${status.index == bettingpool.tieBreakerIndex}">
                checked
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <input type='submit' name='save' value='Save'/>
    <input type='submit' name='save' value='Open Pool' />
</form>
</body>
```

However,I am getting an error like

> `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException`: Property 'tieBreakerIndex' not found on type `dyna.pool.BettingPool`

Any idea how I can access the static field of the class from the jsp page?
thanks

mark.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `static` method , in other word make it non static getter method .Because JSTL EL looks for standard accessors method.

Answer (score -1):

Call your static method differently by adding an import of your class to your jsp at the top.

```
<%@ page import = "yourpackage.BettingPool" %>
.....
.....
<c:if test="${status.index == BettingPool.getTieBreakerIndex()}">
            checked
        </c:if>
```

Comment: I tried this..but gets an error.."The function getTieBreakerIndex must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified"